# Grails 3 with repository mirror

Tags: gradle, grails-3.0

how can grails 3 be configured to fetch all dependencies through a repository mirror?

With maven, such a mirror can easily be configured in the local settings.xml.

When I already have a grails project, I can specify the mirror repository in the build.gradle file.

But when I need to do a `grails create-app` there is no `build.gradle` file yet.

With gradle, I can use an `ini.gradle` file, but will this also work with grails?

Answer (score 0):

`grails create-app` should be creating the **build.gradle** file as default and managing the dependencies + repositories. Is the build system since [Grails 3.0](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/single.html#gradleBuild)

When you run `grails create-app` the build.gradle is not being created?

Maybe there is a version conflict, try `grails -version` from where you launch create-app.